# Filter lines with the other set of lines in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep, filtering, stdin

I have lines on my standard input

```
$printf "C\nB\nA\n"
C
B
A
```

and I want to filter out lines (or substrings or regexps - whatever is easier) that appear on some other standard input:

```
$printf "B\nA\n"
B
A
```

I expect just `C` when entries get filtered.

I've tried with

```
$printf "C\nB\nA\n" | grep -v `printf "B\nA\n"`
```

But then I'm getting

```
grep: A: No such file or directory
```

How can I perform filtering of standard input by lines returned by other command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `grep`'s `-f` option:

```
Matching Control
    -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.
          [...]
```

and use the `<(command)` syntax for using a command's output as the content to be used:

```
$ printf "C\nB\nA\nA\nC\nB" | grep -vf <(printf "A\nB\n")
C
C
```

Answer (score 2):

Use awk to get control of how each line should match each other:

```
$ printf "C\nB\nA\n" | awk 'NF == FNR { a[$0] = 1; next } a[$0]' \
  <(printf "A\nB\n") -
```

By changing `a[$0]` you can define how each should match, i.e to print lines
from file1.txt which first column are in file2.txt:

```
$ awk 'NF == FNR { a[$0] = 1; next } a[$1]' file2.txt file1.txt
#                                      ^ Print if column 1 from file1.txt
#                                        is in file2.txt
```

To print lines from file1.txt which are contained in column one from file2.txt:

```
$ awk 'NF == FNR { a[$1] = 1; next } a[$0]' file2.txt file1.txt
#                                      ^ Print if line from file1.txt match
#                    ^ Store column one from file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```
printf "C\nB\nA\n" | grep -v C
```

and subsequently

```
printf "C\nB\nA\n" | grep -v C | grep -v B
```

then

```
printf "C\nB\nA\n" | grep -v A | grep -v B
```

if you want to do it from a file
assuming file contains

```
C
B
A
```

then:

```
cat file | grep -v B | grep -v A
```

will print

```
C
```

if you want to filter by only piping once

```
cat file | grep -v 'B\|A'
C
```

Comment: The thing is that my both inputs are dynamic (based on `curl` result) and I don't want to create any intermediate files.

Comment: that should work too, by inputs you mean the fields to filter? or what you are piping? if it's what you are piping then just change 'cat file' to whatever you are want to run if ifs the string to filter where would this "variable" come from?

Comment: Lines to filter and the filter itself is dynamic and separated by newlines (not `\|`). So `\`curl input1\` | grep -v \`curl input2\`` doesn't work

Comment: from the grep man: In  basic  regular  expressions the metacharacters ?, +, {, |, (, and )
       lose their special meaning; instead use the  backslashed  versions  \?,
       \+, \{, \|, \(, and \). - is not the separation by another "variable" or string to match...

Comment: that should work. I've tried this... "read -p "where from: " -r url ; read -p "delete: " -r string; curl $url | grep -v $string" whith url google.com and string BODY and it deletes the whole line where it finds the match...

Comment: In my case I need to filter out multiple patterns based on dynamic input, while above you provided example how to filter out just a single pattern.

Comment: Try this... `read -p "where from: " -r url ; read -p "delete: " -r string; read -p "delete2: " -r string2; curl $url | grep -v "$string\|$string2"`